# How do you modify modules/templates without waiting for the cache?

Tags: caching

I'm a beginner at both php and drupal, I know some PHP, at least enough to modify templates and add/remove content from modules, but what irks me is that I always have to wait around 60 seconds for the changes to be visible.

Now I've heard about using the Admin Menu to flush all caches, I've tried every single module that claims to flush the cache, but I still have to wait 60 seconds for the changes to appear

I've also tried disabling the cache by modifying settings.php, to no avail.

As I've said, I'm a beginner at both php and drupal, is this a browser-side cache? or am I missing something?

Comment: Probably it is related to the server settings.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely is a server-side-cache related issue. I have also experienced this with my hosting. Try contacting your hosting provider about this issue or try to find a setting to turn off the server cache in your hosting's admin panel.

Comment: I'm using the Bitnami Drupal stack